# displaying cookies through python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cookies

I wanted to print cookies into text file printcooki.txt. And open a webpage https://www.google.co.in. But at end I am getting blank text file and webpage not opening. What changes to be made in my program ? . Please help me out.

```
     from urllib2 import Request, build_opener, HTTPCookieProcessor, HTTPHandler
    import cookielib
    import io

    object = cookielib.CookieJar()
    opener = build_opener(HTTPCookieProcessor(object), HTTPHandler())
    webreq = Request("https://www.google.co.in/")
    f = opener.open(webreq)
    html = f.read()
    print html[:10]
    print "the webpage has following cookies "
    for cookie in object:
          print>> cookie

    createtext = open("C:\Users\****\Desktop\printcooki.txt", "w")
    print>> cookies ' #to save cookies into printcooki.txt

    opener.open('https://www.google.co.in') #to open a webpage
```

Comment: Unrelated, but, using `urllib2` module can be painful. Have you tried `requests` module ?

Comment: @ShadyProgrammer My program running good with urllib2 module.  Now i can see my cookies. Added to this program , i tried to print the cookies object into text file and open the webpage but I could not end up. I made some changes in code can you please let me know the what is error while printing the cookie in textfile and opening the webpage in same program. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your company makes use of a corporate firewall.

In such a case - and if you have the needed credentials - you can set a couple of environment variables to instruct `urllib2` to use your corporate proxy.
For example in Bash you can run the following commands:

```
export HTTP_PROXY="http://<user_name>:<user_password>@<proxy_ip_address_or_name>:<proxy_port>"
export HTTPS_PROXY="$HTTP_PROXY"
```

before running your Python script.